# Как в .net core отловить все ошибки (обработанные и нет)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Надо отловить все ошибки в приложении, которые не обработаны и обработанные тоже, для ведения логгов, пробовал через **middleware**, **filters**, не получилось.

Проблема в том, что не получается отловить ошибки, которые уже были обработаны **try/catch**, а мне нужно их поймать что бы вытянуть **Message** и **StackTrace** и записать в базу

Comment: Если исключение было поймано (catch) и повторно не выброшено (throw), то всё - его больше нет. Логировать нужно именно в месте отлова ошибок.

Comment: Напишите метод, делающий запись в базу исключения, и вызывайте его из каждого `catch` передавая ему пойманный `Exception` как аргумент. Не пойманные эксепшны все ломают, и логировать их средствами приложения проблематично, потому что упавшее приложение уже не сможет ничего логировать. [Ссылка про необработанные исключения и их логирование](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47679514/12888024)

Comment: Все исключения можно поймать через [AppDomain.FirstChanceException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1). Но как говорится в документации стэк будет не полный. И нужно понимать что исключение в обработчике этого события может вызывать Stackoverflow.

Comment: Как вариант, можно использовать логирующие декораторы. Это стандартный приём - вынесение логирования в класс-декоратор. Таким образом класс предметной области не засоряется кодом логирования.